# Centering Item without using anchors.centerIn: parent

Tags: qml

I have following QML code:

```
ApplicationWindow
{
    id: ueMainWindow

    title: qsTr("testApp")

    width: Screen.desktopAvailableWidth
    height: Screen.desktopAvailableWidth

    visibility: "FullScreen"

    visible: true

    opacity: 1.0

    contentOrientation: Qt.LandscapeOrientation

    color: "black"

    UeCentralWidget
    {
        id: ueCentralWidget

        implicitWidth: contentItem.implicitWidth
        implicitHeight: contentItem.implicitHeight

        //anchors.centerIn: parent

        visible: false
        enabled: false
        opacity: 0.0
    }   // Rectangle
}   // ApplicationWindow
```

Now, if I uncomment line `anchors.centerIn: parent`, the windows position is correct, by I get following QML warnings/errors:

> file:///opt/QtOpenSource55/5.5/gcc_64/qml/QtQuick/Controls/ApplicationWindow.qml:236:9:
>   QML ContentItem: Binding loop detected for property "implicitWidth"
>   file:///opt/QtOpenSource55/5.5/gcc_64/qml/QtQuick/Controls/ApplicationWindow.qml:236:9:
>   QML ContentItem: Binding loop detected for property "implicitWidth"
>   file:///opt/QtOpenSource55/5.5/gcc_64/qml/QtQuick/Controls/ApplicationWindow.qml:236:9:
>   QML ContentItem: Binding loop detected for property "implicitWidth"
>   file:///opt/QtOpenSource55/5.5/gcc_64/qml/QtQuick/Controls/ApplicationWindow.qml:236:9:
>   QML ContentItem: Binding loop detected for property "implicitWidth"
>   file:///opt/QtOpenSource55/5.5/gcc_64/qml/QtQuick/Controls/ApplicationWindow.qml:236:9:
>   QML ContentItem: Binding loop detected for property "implicitWidth"
>   file:///opt/QtOpenSource55/5.5/gcc_64/qml/QtQuick/Controls/ApplicationWindow.qml:236:9:
>   QML ContentItem: Binding loop detected for property "implicitWidth"
>   file:///opt/QtOpenSource55/5.5/gcc_64/qml/QtQuick/Controls/ApplicationWindow.qml:236:9:
>   QML ContentItem: Binding loop detected for property "implicitHeight"
>   file:///opt/QtOpenSource55/5.5/gcc_64/qml/QtQuick/Controls/ApplicationWindow.qml:236:9:
>   QML ContentItem: Binding loop detected for property "implicitHeight"
>   file:///opt/QtOpenSource55/5.5/gcc_64/qml/QtQuick/Controls/ApplicationWindow.qml:236:9:
>   QML ContentItem: Binding loop detected for property "implicitWidth"
>   file:///opt/QtOpenSource55/5.5/gcc_64/qml/QtQuick/Controls/ApplicationWindow.qml:236:9:
>   QML ContentItem: Binding loop detected for property "implicitWidth"
>   file:///opt/QtOpenSource55/5.5/gcc_64/qml/QtQuick/Controls/ApplicationWindow.qml:236:9:
>   QML ContentItem: Binding loop detected for property "implicitWidth"
>   file:///opt/QtOpenSource55/5.5/gcc_64/qml/QtQuick/Controls/ApplicationWindow.qml:236:9:
>   QML ContentItem: Binding loop detected for property "implicitWidth"
>   file:///opt/QtOpenSource55/5.5/gcc_64/qml/QtQuick/Controls/ApplicationWindow.qml:236:9:
>   QML ContentItem: Binding loop detected for property "implicitHeight"
>   file:///opt/QtOpenSource55/5.5/gcc_64/qml/QtQuick/Controls/ApplicationWindow.qml:236:9:
>   QML ContentItem: Binding loop detected for property "implicitHeight"
>   file:///opt/QtOpenSource55/5.5/gcc_64/qml/QtQuick/Controls/ApplicationWindow.qml:236:9:
>   QML ContentItem: Binding loop detected for property "implicitWidth"
>   file:///opt/QtOpenSource55/5.5/gcc_64/qml/QtQuick/Controls/ApplicationWindow.qml:236:9:
>   QML ContentItem: Binding loop detected for property "implicitWidth"
>   qrc:/main.qml:34:5: QML Item: Possible anchor loop detected on
>   centerIn.
>   file:///opt/QtOpenSource55/5.5/gcc_64/qml/QtQuick/Controls/ApplicationWindow.qml:236:9:
>   QML ContentItem: Binding loop detected for property "implicitWidth"
>   file:///opt/QtOpenSource55/5.5/gcc_64/qml/QtQuick/Controls/ApplicationWindow.qml:236:9:
>   QML ContentItem: Binding loop detected for property "implicitWidth"
>   file:///opt/QtOpenSource55/5.5/gcc_64/qml/QtQuick/Controls/ApplicationWindow.qml:236:9:
>   QML ContentItem: Binding loop detected for property "implicitHeight"
>   file:///opt/QtOpenSource55/5.5/gcc_64/qml/QtQuick/Controls/ApplicationWindow.qml:236:9:
>   QML ContentItem: Binding loop detected for property "implicitHeight"

How do I center this `Item` without using `anchors.centerIn: parent` so I can get rid of these errors/warnings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

look carefuly into the `ContentItem` code

```
 function __calcImplicitWidth() {
        if (__layoutItem && __layoutItem.anchors.fill)
            return __calcImplicit('Width')
        return contentItem.childrenRect.x + contentItem.childrenRect.width
    }

    function __calcImplicitHeight() {
        if (__layoutItem && __layoutItem.anchors.fill)
            return __calcImplicit('Height')
        return contentItem.childrenRect.y + contentItem.childrenRect.height
    }
```

`implicitheight` and `implicitWidth` of the content item depends on the `x, y, width and height` of its children,
your object(`UeCentralWidget`) is a child of the contentItem.
when you are writing

```
   implicitWidth: contentItem.implicitWidth
   implicitHeight: contentItem.implicitHeight
```

you are doing a binding loop.

`anchors.centerIn: parent` is not the problem, try  changing your code to:

```
implicitWidth:  20
implicitHeight: 20
```

the proper solution, I think, is to give a static width and height to your object.

If not live with this warnings, cause with a workaround you are hiding the problem not solving it.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe there are different ways to solve this, but the simplest way I know is to set `implicitWidth` and `implicitHeight` once `UeCentralWidget` is completely loaded.

Please let me change `UeCentralWidget` and use a `Rectangle` instead. The next code works fine because we set the properties once the full QML environment has been established.

```
import QtQuick 2.5
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4

ApplicationWindow
{
    id: ueMainWindow

    title: qsTr("testApp")

    width: Screen.desktopAvailableWidth
    height: Screen.desktopAvailableWidth

    visibility: "FullScreen"

    visible: true

    opacity: 1.0

    contentOrientation: Qt.LandscapeOrientation

    color: "black"

    Rectangle {
        id: rectangle
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        color: "red"

        visible: true
        enabled: false

        // implicitWidth: contentItem.implicitWidth
        // implicitHeight: contentItem.implicitHeight

        Component.onCompleted: {
            rectangle.implicitWidth = contentItem.implicitWidth
            rectangle.implicitHeight = contentItem.implicitHeight
        }
    } // Rectangle
}   // ApplicationWindow
```